# htaccess redirect to anchor properly but doesn't rename

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^Skills$ http://mypage/resume.php#Skills [NE,NC,L]
```

Which redirects properly to the anchor link when I have the url: `http://mypage/Skills.`
However the URL in the browser shows the actual anchor link: `http://mysite/resume.php#Skills`
Instead of showing me `http://mysite.com/Skills`

How can I redirect and rewrite the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is redirecting the browser because you have an `http://mypage` in front of your `RewriteRule` target. This automatically tells the rewrite engine you want a 302 redirect so the address bar of your browser is going to be changed. However, the problem here is if you remove it so that it's just `/resume.php#Skills`, it will internally rewrite the request (preserving what is in your browser's address bar) but the fragment (the #Skills) will be useless.

Fragments are used on the client side to tell it to handle the content that it requested in a certain way, usually, to page to where there is a named anchor. If the browser doesn't see the `#Skills`, it isn't going to page to the "Skills" named anchor. If you don't redirect, the browser won't see the fragment because it is being internally handled by the server and the server is going to ignore the fragment.

There may be some kind of javascript solution that tells the browser that the content it just loaded `http://mypage/resume.php` needs to be paged to a certain named anchor. It may be able to do it by looking at the browser's address bar, seeing that it is requesting `/Skills`, and onload() it pages to the `Skills` anchor.